# how to get data use fetch API correctly in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cors, fetch

I'm trying to fetch data from the backend using the GET method, but I always fail to get the data. I get the following error: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing. I don't know how it happens because I tried to use POST method to my backend it worked.

Here's a capture of my browser tools

[image]

When I use `fetch` to get data it always sends 2 requests, first a OPTIONS then a GET. After every request I get this error, then I try to resend request through browser tools, and it works without errors.

Here's my code:

```
    fetch("https://sample.com/api-v2/product/group",{
  headers:{
    'Token' : 'asdf213sacxcv'
  }
})
  .then(function (response) {
    if (response.status !== 200) {
      console.log(
        "Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: " + response.status
      );
      return;
    }

    // Examine the text in the response
    response.json().then(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log("Fetch Error :-S", err);
  });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to enable CORS on the server to run cross-origin requests, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your backend application runs on a different domain than your client application?
That causes the CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing error because basically your client-side is not authorized to access your backend using its domain.
Add cors headers in your first middleware in the backend.
you can set a header of

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'
```

to allow **any** origin to access the backend.

Or setting your specific domain to allow only it to access your backend.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 'https://example.com'
```

Where https://example.com is the domain of your client side application.

Comment: Better allow just the specific origin rather than blanket allowing any origin.

Comment: of course, just stating the fastest most obvious solution...